# Way to generate all multisets

Tags: list-manipulation, programming, combinatorics

I have a set $\left\{\{1,2\}, \{3,4\}, \{5,6\}, \{7,8\}\right\}$ (for example) and want to generate all sets of $n$ elements with repetition but without counting the same multiset twice. So I want my generated list to contain: (say $n$ = 3)

$\{\{1,2\}, \{1,2\}, \{3,4\}\}$ and $\{\{1,2\}, \{3,4\}, \{5,6\}\}$ but I don't also want $\{\{1,2\}, \{3,4\}, \{1,2\}\}$ as that should be the same as the first set. (Well, I want this set but flattened, like $\{1,2,1,2,3,4\}$, etc, but I kept the brackets in to be more illustrative.)

Example: I have $\{\{1,2\}, \{3,4\}, \{5,6\}\}$ and $n =2$, then I want to generate
$\{\{1,2,1,2\}, \{1,2,3,4\},\{1,2,5,6\}, \{3,4,3,4\}, \{3,4,5,6\}, \{5,6,5,5\}\} $

The only way I can think of is making a table then write some long loop thing to remove the repetitions and I'm sure there's a much more efficient way to do this. Probably invoke constant array somehow but I really have no idea how to implement it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: `Union[Sort /@ Tuples[Partition[Range[8], 2], 3]]`?

Comment: Flatten /@ Tuples[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}}, {2}] ?

Comment: @J.M. This works nicely, thanks!

Comment: @Prashanth This is close, but there is repetion. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data:

```
data = Partition[Range[8], 2];
```

Read the documentation for [`Tuples`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tuples.html) as recommended by J.M and  Prashanth.

```
Tuples[data, 3]
```

Generates a list of all possible 3-tuples of elements from list.

Because order is nor relevant you will have duplicates. So you need to sort and remove the permutations.

```
multisets[data_, n_] := Union[Sort /@ Tuples[data, n]]
```

Now use with `n -> 3`

```
multisets[data, 3]
```

> ```
> {{{1, 2}, {1, 2}, {1, 2}}, {{1, 2}, {1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{1, 2}, {1, 
>    2}, {5, 6}}, {{1, 2}, {1, 2}, {7, 8}}, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {3, 
>    4}}, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {7, 8}}, {{1, 
>    2}, {5, 6}, {5, 6}}, {{1, 2}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}}, {{1, 2}, {7, 8}, {7,
>     8}}, {{3, 4}, {3, 4}, {3, 4}}, {{3, 4}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}, {{3, 
>    4}, {3, 4}, {7, 8}}, {{3, 4}, {5, 6}, {5, 6}}, {{3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7,
>     8}}, {{3, 4}, {7, 8}, {7, 8}}, {{5, 6}, {5, 6}, {5, 6}}, {{5, 
>    6}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}}, {{5, 6}, {7, 8}, {7, 8}}, {{7, 8}, {7, 8}, {7,
>     8}}}
> ```

Comment: Thanks for this! Very helpful. There is a small error though which I can't edit because it's not 6 characters? But it should be `Tuples[data,n]]`.